# It's really difficult to exercise my triceps, could use some suggestions!

Tags: triceps

Whenever I try to exercise my triceps, my elbows REALLY hurt. This is something recent.

Normally I would bring about 45 pounds behind my head and do 15-20 reps, and lowering the weight didn't help at all. I brought the weight down to 20 pounds and it still hurts like hell.

![**(Picture)**
**(Picture)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30VHF.jpg)

Referring to the picture, when I do anything to stimulate the triceps, it feels as if the Lateral Epicondyle and the Olecranon are scraping against one another violently. This is where all of the pain is coming from.

I have correct form when doing my workouts and dropping the weight didn't work.
I've been taking in a lot of calcium and protein in hopes that it will help, but it isn't doing much, is there anything else to try?
And thanks!

Comment: If you are using proper form and it hurts, something is not right. Off to the doctor you go!

Comment: How were you working your triceps?  Also, ahve a look at this video http://startingstrength.com/index.php/site/video/platform_the_lying_triceps_extension

Comment: Haha you're comment genuinely made me laugh, John xD

Comment: And thanks for the link :)
Gave me a better understanding.
And what I usually end up doing is I put a weight up and over behind my head. It's hard to describe..

I pull the weight up and behind my head and just do reps from there, don't really know how to describe it further :S

Comment: Do they hurt when you do ANY tricep exercises? Or just the overhead presses? Also, do you use one hand at a time or both on the weight?

Comment: I second JohnP recommendation to see a doctor. Also, I would suggest finding alternate ways to workout the triceps. There are tons of amazing exercises, not the least of which include pulls ups, push ups, chair dips, bench press, and over head barbell press. You may find that the pain is relegated only to that specific workout, and these other exercises may then prove safe to use.

Comment: @Grohlier It hurt with just about all, and I would usually use both hands as it was easier to control the weight.

@ Moses Yeah right now it seems dips and pull ups work best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar problems with my triceps and the best exercise I've found is [doing dips.](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/dips-triceps-version) But to start out you might want to try them [with the assistance of a bench](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/bench-dips) or a machine.

Comment: I'll definitely keep this in mind :)
Should I just do flat out dips or throw weight on my shoulders or just work my way up?

and thanks :)

Comment: I'd say try just the dips with your ouwn body weight and if you can do 3 sets and a decent amount of reps 7-12 without struggling or feeling winded, then maybe add weight belt. If that seems like too much, then definitely start with the help of the bench. And, Sorry for the caps lock but I just want to say: DO NOT TRY TO LIFT MORE THAN YOU ARE ABLE, YOU MAY INJURE YOURSELF!

Comment: Okay, and thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!!